# How to keep access keys safe in the event of a compromised server?

Tags: linux, security

What's the best strategy to keeping access tokens secure in the event of a compromised server?

Let's say I have a Linux web server to which I regularly ssh into. There is a variety of critical access tokens stored on this server (e.g. encryption keys, Amazon S3 for backups, etc). If an attacker can ssh into the server, what's the best strategy to prevent them from reading the keys?

Comment: Start by setting up a certificate based VPN for all activity except the web server's web activity.  Make sure to also [harden your sshd_config further](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112365/39623), also starting with certificate based logins only, in addition to the mitigations in the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty hard to keep keys from being read. Mandatory access control on your daemons using AppArmor or SELinux will kick up the ability to limit read access.

Making use of software like [Vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vault.html) kicks it up a notch. Like the temporary credential system given by Amazon's STS, this can be applied to any backend you write a module for a few exist thus creating temporary and easily revocable credentials. If written directly into your app, this will keep passwords outside of configuration files.

You can use an authentication backend such as the [App ID](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/app-id.html) one or if you have hardware, get super fancy and write a TPM based one.

Answer (score 6):

1. Encryption keys should be asymmetric, so if they fall into someone else's hands, they can't do anything but encrypt data with the keys (not decrypt).
2. S3 credentials should be rotated frequently and automatically, and should be only given the **bare** minimum of access to buckets. Backup keys should *only* have PUT access to buckets, not list/delete/modify/get, etc. Likewise, if these keys fall into the wrong hands, all they can do is push more data to you.
3. Implement the standard means to protect a server: Key authentication, strong passwords for sudo access, etc.
4. Use a HIDS (like OSSEC) to audit file access/modification and alert on anomalies.
5. Only give read access to keys to the specific users that need them.

Beyond that, you're looking at needing to use an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), which adds quite a bit of expense and complexity. If you're already on AWS, they have a key management service that you can use to protect and audit usage of your keys.